Type checking for pipeline similar to Langchain LCEL
I am trying to write a pipeline with types that will give errors if the steps are not compatible step1() | step2().
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, TypeVar

I = TypeVar('I')
O = TypeVar('O')
R = TypeVar('R')

class Runnable(Generic[I, O]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[I], O]) -> None:
        self.func = func
    
    # not sure how to make it work with multiple arguments
    # def __or__(self, other: Callable[[O], R]):
    #     def chained_func(*args: I, **kwargs):
    #         output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    #         return other(output)
    #     return Runnable(chained_func)
    
    def __or__(self, other: Callable[[O], R]):
        def chained_func(input: I):
            output = self.func(input)
            return other(output)
        # has type Unknown instead of I, hence why I specify [I, R] explicity
        return Runnable[I, R](chained_func)
    

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    
def add_five(x: int):
    return x + 5

def parse(x:str):
    return x.strip()

add_five = Runnable(add_five) # Runnable[int, int]
parse = Runnable(parse) # Runnable[str, str]

chain = add_five | parse
chain(3)

(code based on this video)
add_five: Runnable[int, int], parse: Runnable[str, str] and chain: Runnable[int, str], but there is no (type hint) error to indicate that the output of add_five is not compatible with the input of parse. Can this be achieved?
